# Convert int to ascii [chr()] in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, ascii, chr

I am writing a django application, and in a loop,

```
    {% for item in list %}
    {{ forloop.counter0 }}
    {% endfor %}
```

this will printout the number in the loop starting from 0. But I want to printout alphabet starting from 'A', so the python way to do it is chr(forloop.counter0+65), but this is inside the template, any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write a simple [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/), for example a filter:

```
@register.filter(name='chr')
def chr_(value):
    return chr(value + 65)
```

Then load it in your template and you can do:

```
{{ forloop.counter0|chr }}
```